# Swift GameKit Moving Sprite In Arc

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gamekit

I need some help in making the player in my platform game jump. The problem I'm having is that he jumps through a pillar which he's not supposed to do (I do have the physics set up correctly). I suspect it is because of my horribly inefficient code below.  I know there's a better way to move him along a path but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
var xStep = CGFloat(18)
var yStep = CGFloat(30)

var x = CGFloat(playerJump.position.x)
var y = CGFloat(playerJump.position.y)

let follow = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y += yStep
let follow2 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y += yStep
let follow3 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y += yStep
let follow4 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y += yStep
let follow5 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y -= yStep
let follow6 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y -= yStep
let follow7 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y -= yStep
let follow8 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)
x += xStep
y -= yStep
let follow9 = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y:y), duration: 0.1)

let group = SKAction.group([
    SKAction.repeat(jumpAnimation!, count: 1),
           SKAction.sequence([follow,follow2,follow3,follow4,follow5,follow6,follow7,follow8,follow9])
])
if playerJump.parent == nil {
    addChild(playerJump)
}
playerJump.run(SKAction.sequence([group]), completion: {
    self.player.position=self.playerJump.position
    self.playerJump.removeAllActions()
    self.playerJump.removeFromParent()
    self.addChild(self.player)
})
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**UPDATE**
The problem started when I increased the value in xStep.  The total distance the character jumps would put it past the pillar.  That's why I thought my code was an issue.  Here's a video of what's happening.
[Jumping Video](http://maccrafters.com/videos/game.mov)

**UPDATE 2**
Here's my newest code which still puts the player on the other side of the pillar.

```
@objc func jumpTapped() {
    var xStep = CGFloat(18)
    let yStep = CGFloat(12)

    jumping=true
    xStep = player.xScale * xStep
    var x = player.position.x
    var y = player.position.y


    var moveAnimation = [SKAction]()

    for i in 0...8 {
        x += xStep
        if i < 5 {
            y += yStep
        } else {
            y -= yStep
        }
        let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), duration: 0.1)
        moveAnimation.append(move)
    }

    let group = SKAction.group([jumpAnimation!, SKAction.sequence(moveAnimation)])

    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    player.removeAllActions()
    player.run(group) {
        self.endJump()
    }
}

func endJump() {
    player.removeAllActions()
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(self.playerAnimation!))
    jumping=false
}
```

Comment: Your really asking 2 things here, and they are unrelated. If you want help figuring out why your character jumps through the pillar you need to show some physics code, graphics and/or video showing of what is happening (making with the physics boundaries turned on in your scene). Inefficient code should not factor into physics, and don't assume that you do have the physics setup properly until it can be ruled out.

Comment: see my edit in my answer as to why I think that you are having this issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting player.position to self.playerJump.position

That is probably your problem, it is jumping beyond where the pillar is. You might as well have said player.position.x = player.position.x + 500 which will put you on the other side of the pillar as well ignoring any physics all together.

Why are you adding a sprite and running the actions on it? why not just run the animation and the actions on the player sprite?

As far as cleaning up your code goes you can try this. there are other things you can do as well like have the character jump along a Bezier path but this might be fine for what you are doing. But I highly doubt this will have any impact on your issue of the player jumping through the pillar.

Some small tidbits for you.

Sprite positions are already a CGFloat no need to cast them

short hand completion code syntax is `object.run(someAction) { //do something when complete }`

running an action with repeat of 1 is pointless

running a sequence of a single action (`SKAction.sequence([group])`) is also pointless

```
var xStep = CGFloat(18)
var yStep = CGFloat(30)

var x = playerJump.position.x
var y = playerJump.position.y
var moveAnimation: [SKAction]!

for _ in 0...9 {
    x += xStep
    y += yStep
    moveAnimation.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), duration: 0.1))
}

let group = SKAction.group([jumpAnimation, SKAction.sequence(moveAnimation)])

guard playerJump.parent else { addChild(playerJump)}

playerJump.run(group) {
    self.player.position = self.playerJump.position
    self.playerJump.removeAllActions()
    self.playerJump.removeFromParent()
    self.addChild(self.player)
}
```

> Edit try adding the below function to your code

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let contactAName = contact.bodyA.node?.name
    let contactBName = contact.bodyB.node?.name

    if (contactAName == "pillar") || (contactBName == "pillar") {
        //assuming only player can hit pillar so don't need to check if one of the contacts is player
        endJump()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I eliminated playerJump and just added the animation to player (as you suggested).  However, the result is still the same.  During the jump, the physics engine prevents the player from going through the pillar.  However, when it's over, the position is still getting set to the other side of the pillar.  If the player body and pillar body aren't touching at the start of the jump, it works just fine.  If they are touching and the jump starts, that's when it ends up on the other side.

Comment: please edit your answer with your new code so I can check it out

Comment: @FloydResler check out the edit in my answer and see if that works

Comment: Unfortunately, that still didn't work.  I have the pillar set up in the player's collision and contact bitmask.  For some reason the didBegin doesn't fire during the animation when the pillar is contacted.  It does, however, for my ladders which are only set in the players contact bitmask.  I did find a workaround, however.  If the player makes contact with the pillar before jumping, the didBegin and didEnd events fire.  So, if the player is next to the pillar I just prevent the jump from happening.

Comment: @FloydResler I did spend a lot of time on this question and on another question of yours in the past. The arrows on answers are if you find the answer useful.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the time you put into my questions.  I clicked on the up arrow.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  My mistake was moving the sprite within the SKAction.  I should have been moving the sprite in the update method.  So, I added this to update():

```
    if jumping {
            if jumpCount > 3 {
                player.position.x += xStep // Jump straight up for a couple of frames to clear steps
            }
            if jumpCount < maxJump/2 {
                player.position.y += yStep  //Move sprite up for first half of jump
            } else {
                player.position.y -= yStep //Move sprite down for last half of jump
            }
            jumpCount += 1
            if jumpCount >= maxJump {
                endJump()
            }
        }
```

All the collision detection works properly and the player doesn't jump through pillars.